# Лимит пиров/сидов

Tags: torrent

Какое максимальное количество пиров/сидов может отдавать трекер? Есть ли какие нибудь ограничения или рекомендации?

Comment: сильно много не надо, если dht разрешен.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендация: чем больше, тем лучше. Конкретнее зависит скорее от железа. 
Если вспомнить, что трафик через трекер почти не идет(а трафик раздач не идет вообще), основную нагрузку создают копеечные обращения клиента и скачивания превьюшек.

Рассчитывайте 200-500 сидов на хорошую раздачу. Пиров - раз в 10 больше.

Comment: дело в том, что в том же TBDev по дефолту стоит лимит на выборку приров/сидов из базы - 50. возможно чем то обусловлено данное ограничение?

Comment: тем что есть другие раздачи.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос решен